# RESTful WCF (4.5.2) service errors with "413 Entity Request Too Large"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, rest

this seems to be a really common question - and I've read through a ton of comments here on SO and other sites.  Problem is that even after fixing up my configuration I'm still getting the 413 error when sending an ~50K payload.

Here's the relevant portion of the service config...

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
<services>
  <service name="Sync.Inbound" behaviorConfiguration="serviceWebConfiguration">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingName="defaultRest" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="Sync.IInbound"  />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="defaultRest" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp  />
      <dataContractSerializer  maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"  />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="json">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceWebConfiguration">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I'm testing by calling this from a simple C# console application via an httpWebRequest...  Anybody see anything I'm missing in the service config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `bindingConfiguration` attribute to `"defaultRest"` on the ***service endpoint*** element, otherwise the service will not use the specified binding configuration block.

The sample above shows the binding configuration name in a "bindingName" attribute rather than the "bindingConfiguration" attribute.
Therefore, you need to change:

```
<endpoint ... bindingName="defaultRest"
```

to:

```
<endpoint ... bindingConfiguration="defaultRest"
```

Example:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <services>
      <service name="Sync.Inbound" behaviorConfiguration="serviceWebConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultRest" ...
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultRest" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733099(v=vs.110).aspx
[bindingConfiguration vs bindingName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491420/bindingconfiguration-vs-bindingname)

Comment: Thank you Seymour!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change up `maxItemsInObjectGraph` for your services  `dataContractSerializer` to allow larger collections through.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="SecureServiceBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:03:00"/>
    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentSessions="10" maxConcurrentInstances="10"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```