# cant send or receive array with large size in web service wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, web-config

Can't send or receive array with large size in web service (`wcf`)

I have a method in my `Wcf` service that returns `arraylist`. When the count of array is less than `100`, it works. But more than `1000`, I get this error message:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` property on the appropriate binding element.

What's wrong with my web config?

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding" receiveTimeout="00:40:00" 
       sendTimeout="00:40:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
  <service name="KETABMACazvinService.KETABMACazvinService" 
behaviorConfiguration="KETABMACazvinService.KETABMACazvinServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"   
  contract="KETABMACazvinService.IKETABMACazvinService">

      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="KETABMACazvinService.KETABMACazvinServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below 
  to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: The server may have limits on the size of the downloads or you may be exceeding a timeout.  How long does it take for the error message to occur? If the error is happening in 5 seconds then you are probably exceeding the size.  If the error is taking around 30 seconds then it indicates you hit a timeout.

Comment: @jdweng about 2 seconds

Comment: @jdweng would you please take a look at my webconfig code?

Comment: It is a limit that you cannot control.  An admin property on the Machine has a limit.

Comment: Why don't you have a `bindingConfiguration` attribute on your service endpoint to indicate you want to use the `MyBasicHttpBindimng` config? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491420/bindingconfiguration-vs-bindingname

Comment: @jdweng yes, I correct it acccording to this link answers  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota

Comment: Which solution worked so other people reading this posting know the solution.  The link you provided has a lot of different solutions.  Is it the one with the check mark?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good, we are supposed to increase the value of the MaxReceivedMessageSize property. One thing we also should pay attention to is that we should apply the configuration to the actual service endpoint by using **bindingConfiguration** property of the endpoint section.

Please refer to the below code segments.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
  contract="KETABMACazvinService.IKETABMACazvinService" bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.